# How to mount Azure Blob Storage (hierarchical namespace disabled) from Databricks

Tags: azure-databricks

I need to mount Azure Blob storage (where hierarchical namespace is disabled) from databricks. Mount command returns true but when I run fs.ls command, it returns error UnknownHostException. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar kind of error. I tried and unmounted my blob storage account. Then, Remounted my storage account. Now, it's working fine.

**Unmounting Storage account:**

```
dbutils.fs.unmount("<mount_point>")
```

[image]

**Mount Blob Storage:**

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = "wasbs://<container>@<Storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point = "<mount_point>",
    extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.vamblob.blob.core.windows.net":"Access_key"})

display(dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/fgs'))
```

[image]

This command `display(dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/fgs'))` returns all the files available in the mount point. You can perform all the required operations and then write to this DBFS, which will be reflected in your blob storage container also.

For more information refer this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-use-databricks-spark).

Comment: Thanks @SaiVamsi .... are you able to mount Azure Blob storage (where hierarchical namespace is "disabled") from databricks. I tried this many times unmounting, creating new mount point but is did not work. I am wondering whether or not it is possible to mount standard Azure Blob with disabled hierarchical namespace.

Comment: @Zuberkhan Pathan in [Azure blob storage](https://i.imgur.com/zA4hsUl.png) hierarchical namespace is always "disabled". If you are using [ADLS gen2](https://i.imgur.com/k4oHz31.png) then its hierarchical namespace is enabled.

Comment: thanks.. so if you saying your mount code worked for Azure Blob Storage then for me it must be some access issue then.. because i can mount ADLS Geb2 but not standard Blob storage..